# Scalate's render tag is not able to resolve the template

Tags: scala, scala-template, scalate

Scalate's render tag is not able to resolve the template and throws the following exception:

org.fusesource.scalate.util.ResourceNotFoundException: Could not load resource: [file:/Users/xxxxx/template/abc-conf.ssp]
    at org.fusesource.scalate.util.ResourceLoader$class.createNotFoundException(ResourceLoader.scala:58)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.util.FileResourceLoader.createNotFoundException(ResourceLoader.scala:61)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.util.ResourceLoader$class.resourceOrFail(ResourceLoader.scala:55)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.util.FileResourceLoader.resourceOrFail(ResourceLoader.scala:61)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.util.UriResource.delegate(Resource.scala:90)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.util.DelegateResource.text(Resource.scala:215)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.ssp.SspCodeGenerator.generate(SspCodeGenerator.scala:152)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoad(TemplateEngine.scala:802)
    a

Comment: It is being used as                                                                                       
 <% render("abc-conf.ssp", Map("a" -> "a")) %>

Comment: It's telling you there isn't a file at `Users/xxxxx/template/abc-conf.ssp`. Where are your templates located?

Comment: Hi, I am keeping templates in CLASSPATH @src/main/resources/templates

Comment: Try prefixing the template path with a `/`. Change it to `render("/abc-conf.ssp", ...` does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for templates in a folder called `template`, but you've told me in your comment that your templates are in a folder called `template*s*`. Rename your folder to `template` and it should work.